# How to export users from Joomla and JomSocial to csv/xls file?

Tags: export, components, joomla3.0

Is there any solution which allows to export users from Joomla and JomSocial into a file ?
It would be also great to have posibility to filter users by some criterias, e.g. registration date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good export solution which can handle this task:
[EXPORT/DOWNLOAD JOMSOCIAL USERS TO EXCEL OR CSV FILE](https://www.ukrsolution.com/Joomla/Export-Users-From-JomSocial-To-Excel-CSV-File)